# Preprocessing the Highstock Chart options

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to preprocess options for a Highstock Chart. i did some debugging with firebug to check if the options are set correctly. but there is a problem with the series definition. when i delete the [] from the series, the option wil be set alright but the chart doesn't render anymore. if i keep the [] at the series the chart shows up but without the definitions in it. Does anyone know what i am missing?

the data array is transmitted correctly. (but not shown in the code)
it contains array of 2 values. e.g: 
    [1336168800000, 22]

```
options = {
    chart : {
        renderTo : 'container'
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 2
    },
    title : {
        text : 'Diary'
    },
    series : [{
        name : 'aaapl',
        lineWidth : 0,
        data: [],
        marker : {
            enabled : true,
            radius : 2
        },
        tooltip : {
            valueDecimals : 2
        }
    }]
};
    chart1 = new Highcharts.StockChart(options);
    chart1.redraw();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do see some errors in the way that you are creating your chart.

- You are not setting [**LineWidth**](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.lineWidth) and [**marker**](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.marker) correctly.  They actually need to fall under [**plotOptions**](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions) and then the chart type.
- Also [**tooltip**](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip) should not be nested inside of the series object.

Comment: i actually went after an example from the highstock demo gallery:

http://jsfiddle.net/EgE6r/

but i will try the changes anyway. thanks for the input